# Integrate ng2-bootstrap with Angular2

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

Been trying to integrate `ng2-bootstrap` with `Angular2 beta.9` using 
**CDN** reference.

[Non working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q005ABRAbe69B7E6GO47?p=preview)

**index.html**

```
 <script>
       System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
        packages: {
          'src': {defaultExtension: 'ts'},
          'ng2-material': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
          'ng2-bootstrap':{defaultExtension: 'js'}
        },
        map: {
                'ng2-material': 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/justindujardin/ng2-material/gh-pages/v/0.2.5/ng2-material',
                'ng2-bootstrap':'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng2-bootstrap/1.0.7/ng2-bootstrap'
            }
      });

      System.import('src/boot.ts')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

**boot.ts**

```
...

import { Alert } from 'ng2-bootstrap';

//let template = require('./alert-demo.html');  <---------what about this?

@Component({
selector: 'my-app', 
  template: `
 <alert *ngFor="#alert of alerts;#i = index" [type]="alert.type" dismissible="true" (close)="closeAlert(i)">
  {{ alert?.msg }}
</alert>

<alert dismissOnTimeout="3000">This alert will dismiss in 3s</alert>

<button type="button" class='btn btn-primary' (click)="addAlert()">Add Alert</butto

   `,
  directives: [childcmp,Alert],

})

export class ParentCmp {

  alerts:Array<Object> = [
    {
      type: 'danger',
      msg: 'Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.'
    },
    {
      type: 'success',
      msg: 'Well done! You successfully read this important alert message.',
      closable: true
    }
  ];

  constructor(public authService: AuthService){

  }


  closeAlert(i:number) {
    this.alerts.splice(i, 1);
  }

  addAlert() {
    this.alerts.push({msg: 'Another alert!', type: 'warning', closable: true});
  }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you need to include the `ng2-bootstrap.js` into a script element and remove it from your SYstemJS configuration.

```
<script>
  System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
    packages: {
      'src': {defaultExtension: 'ts'},
      'ng2-material': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
    },
    map: {
      'ng2-material': 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/justindujardin/ng2-material/gh-pages/v/0.2.5/ng2-material',
    }
  });

  (...)
<script>
```

The problem is the way your try to import the `Alert` component:

```
import { Alert } from 'ng2-bootstrap/components/alert';
```

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/YbONWFhPY0IUkXzYo54u?p=preview.

Comment: It seems that you have other problems in your application ;-) See: "Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'ParentCmp'"

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/hHtW6zTH34HxKCgj8Evx?p=preview now I have only one cmp. i wonder how to get reference from ng2-bootstrap temple `let template = require('./alert-demo.html');`??

Comment: Got it. The problem is the way you import the `Alert` component... I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit angular-cli-build.js file like below

`vendorNpmFiles: [
    'ng2-bootstrap/**/*',
     'moment/moment.js'
]`

Edit src/system-config.ts file like below

```
const map: any = {
     'moment': 'vendor/moment/moment.js',
     'ng2-bootstrap': 'vendor/ng2-bootstrap'
};


/** User packages configuration. */
 const packages: any = {
 'ng2-bootstrap': {
   format: 'cjs',
   defaultExtension: 'js',
   main: 'ng2-bootstrap.js'
 },
 'moment':{
   format: 'cjs'
 }
};
```

Now we are almost done.

```
ng build
```

Above step will create files in the dist/vendor folder and we are done. if you find errors in the code try restarting the server. That is all what you need but if you are interested more I have written an article [here](http://imalhasaranga.com/2016/07/01/how-to-use-ng2-bootstrap-with-angular-cli/)